# Randomizing buttons position in flash

Tags: flash, button

When I start my application, it displays a page with a start button.

Upon clicking it, eight buttons are displayed. For my application, I want that everytime I run it, the buttons should randomize that is they should appear at different positions on the page.

Could anyone please help?

Comment: I am not getting any logic for this. I first tried by creating an array of the instances of the button. Then I shuffled the array so that it becomes random. After that i returned it to the same array name. But, I still can't see the buttons changing their positions. Can you please suggest any idea/solution for this?

Comment: You should shuffle button coords, not the instance handlers itself :)

Answer (score 0):

you have button1...button8

```
var arr:Array = new Array();
for (var i:int=1; i<=8; i++) {
    var btn:Sprite = this["button"+i] as Sprite
    arr.push({x:btn.x, y:btn.y})
}
suffle arr
for (i=1; i<=8; i++) {
    var btn:Sprite = this["button"+i] as Sprite
    btn.x = arr[i-1].x;
    btn.y = arr[i-1].y;
}
```

Comment: Ok..So I suppose I will have to store the button coords in  the array called "arr". but how do i store both x and y coords in a single array?    or do i have to write the instances in the "arr" and their positions will be pushed?  Then the shuffling of "arr" is done...but then how do I ensure that the new/shuffled coords of the buttons are used for changing the position of buttons?

Comment: Did you see the braces? It's the instance of class Object. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html Objects can store many variables in one "container". We put in the array Objects with the coordinates of all buttons. X and Y together. Then shuffle the array. Now, in the array[0] lays object with coords of button5, in array[1] - coordinates of button3, in array[2] - button1 and so on.

Comment: Then we set button1 in coords array[0] (ie, original coords of button5) button 2 to the array[0] (original coords of button3), and so on. Think a little, this is a very simple algorithm. Keep in mind that the array elements are indexed from zero.

Comment: What I understood from your explanation and code is that the "1st for loop" pushes the coords of buttons in the array called "arr". Then "suffle arr" is the code which I will have to write apart from this code to shuffle the array. And, once shuffling has been done the "2nd for loop" will push the new/shuffled coords to the buttons so that they relocate.    Have I got it right? Please confirm..

Comment: var arr:Array = new Array();
for (var i:int=1; i<=6; i++) {
    var btn:Sprite = this["btn"+i] as Sprite
    arr.push({x:btn.x, y:btn.y})
}



for (i=1; i<=6; i++)
{
    btn = this["btn"+i] as Sprite
    btn.x = arr[i-1].x;
    btn.y = arr[i-1].y;
}


function arrayShuffle(array_arr:Array):Array{
   for(i= 0; i < array_arr.length; i++){
      var randomNum_num = Math.floor(Math.random() * array_arr.length)
      var arrayIndex = array_arr[i];
      array_arr[i] = array_arr[randomNum_num];
      array_arr[randomNum_num] = arrayIndex;
   }
   return array_arr;
}

trace(arrayShuffle(arr));

Comment: hey smolniy, this is what i wrote..but the buttons are still at the same location.They have not relocated. Can you please help?

Comment: Hey it is working fine..but i have got 8 scenes where i need to write to write this same code. When i do that, it gives a lot of errors like.             home, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 2 1119: Access of possibly undefined property emphasized through a reference with static type flash.display:Sprite.
home, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 2 1119: Access of possibly undefined property enabled through a reference with static type flash.display:Sprite.
home, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 2 1119: Access of possibly undefined property label through a reference with static type flash.display:Sprite.
please help.

Comment: Maybe you call your algorythm in scope where your buttons not available. Try to trace button before calling function. And here is more simple code... I put it in new answer for readability...

Comment: I'm sorry, SimpleButton doesn't cast to Sprite :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the buttons in an array yo can do something like this:

```
for(1=i; i<=button_array.length; i++) {
    button_array[i].x = Math.random() * WIDTH_AVAILABLE;
    button_array[i].y = Math.random() * HEIGHT_AVAILABLE;
}
```

You should adjust width and height so the buttons doesn't end outside the available space. This also doesn't have any checks for overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

```
function shuffleButtons(arrayOfButton:Array):void {
    trace ("input: " + arrayOfButton)
    for(var i:int=0; i<100; i++) {
        var btn1:DisplayObject = arrayOfButton[Math.floor(Math.random()*arrayOfButton.length)] as DisplayObject;
        do {
            var btn2:DisplayObject = arrayOfButton[Math.floor(Math.random()*arrayOfButton.length)] as DisplayObject;
        } while (btn1==btn2);

        var foo:Number;

        foo = btn1.x;
        btn1.x = btn2.x;
        btn2.x = foo;

        foo = btn1.y;
        btn1.y = btn2.y;
        btn2.y = foo;
    }
}
```

And when you need to suffle set ov buttons, call

`shuffleButtons([button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6 ]);`